# Having an issue with SQL Order by Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table like this in SQL Server 2012:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (dateField datetime,
                     col1 varchar(10),
                     col2 varchar(10)
                    )

insert into @test
   select dateadd(day,-1,getdate()), 'Test A', 'Other A'
   union 
   select dateadd(day,-1,getdate()), 'Test E', 'Other E'
   union 
   select getdate(), 'Test B', 'Other B'
   union 
   select dateadd(day,1,getdate()), 'Test C', 'Other C' 
   union 
   select dateadd(day,1,getdate()), 'Test A', 'Other C'
   union  
   select dateadd(day,1,getdate()), 'Test D', 'Other B'
```

I want to retrieve the data in a specific order.

Order should be:

```
dateField ASC 
Col1 ends with A
Col2 ends with B
```

- If datefield is greater than today's date, then it should switch to col1 check.
- If there's no col1 that ends with A, then it should switch to col2 check
- If there's no col2 that ends with B, no rows should be returned

Any help would be appreciated. I tried doing case statements in SQL. It didn't work as I expected.

Comment: Ordering doesn't eliminate rows. Are you ordering the resulting data or filtering?

Comment: Can you show what have you tried using Case statements?

Comment: Also, please stop using `GETDATE() + 1` - that's +1 .... what?!?!? Second? Minute? Hour? Year? Month? Day? Please instead use the `DATEADD(datepart,.....)` function which makes it **clear** what you're adding or subtracting from a date

Comment: This will be in a stored procedure where each call will retrieve one row at a time. So after the required data is returned, it should not return any more data.

Comment: @Marc_s: Sorry, In my query, I am using dateadd . Just to type it faster, I did this.

Comment: I'm afraid your solution is probably a combination of filtering, sorting, and collating. Show some data for results so we can narrow down the code.

Comment: @Abhi Could you post your expected results  of the query?

Comment: @Ghost: I would expect it like this:
Test A, Other A
Test E, Other E
Test B, Other B
Test A, Other C
Test D, Other B

Answer (score 0):

You seem a bit confused about if it is filtered or sorted or a combination of that. This does both.

```
select
    *
from (
    SELECT
        *
        ,substring(col1,len(col1),1) [LastCharCol1]
        ,substring(col2,len(col2),2) [LastCharCol2]
    FROM @test
) t
where 1=1
AND (
        [LastCharCol1]='A'
    OR  [LastCharCol2]='B'
)
order by CASE WHEN dateField>CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,CASE WHEN [LastCharCol1]='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,CASE WHEN [LastCharCol2]='B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you want to filter records:

```
select *
from @test
where dateField > getdate() and (col1 like '%A' or col2 like '%B')
```